# Joomla update broken updates table

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.3.x, mysql

I have recently updated Joomla from v 3.2.3 to 3.3.6 but for some reason when I'm trying to install anything I'm now getting an error:

```
1146  Table 'dbname.ku42W_updates' doesn't exist SQL=SHOW COLUMNS IN `ku42W_updates`
```

I have tried the following SQL query but it's not working, it's saying table doesn't exist!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ku42W_updates` (
  `update_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `update_site_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `extension_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `element` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `type` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `folder` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `client_id` tinyint(3) DEFAULT 0,
  `version` varchar(32) DEFAULT '',
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `detailsurl` text NOT NULL,
  `infourl` text NOT NULL,
  `extra_query` varchar(1000) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`update_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Available Updates';
```

I have tried creating the database table manually, but then getting the same error.

If I go into Extensions >> Extension Manager >> Database >> Fix, I'm getting the following error:

```
1146 Table 'kingswood.kw_updates' doesn't exist SQL=SHOW COLUMNS IN `kw_updates` WHERE field = 'infourl'
```

Any ideas what I can do to resolve it? Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors if you go to Extensions >> Extension Manager >> Database ?

Comment: I've just updated the question with the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved this by a fresh and clean install of Joomla 3.3.6, then I migrated across all of the relevant database tables. Not pretty (or quick) but it's working now at least!

*** UPDATE ***

This fix works much better:

```
DROP TABLE #####_updates;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#####_updates` (
  `update_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `update_site_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `extension_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `element` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `type` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `folder` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `client_id` tinyint(3) DEFAULT 0,
  `version` varchar(32) DEFAULT '',
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `detailsurl` text NOT NULL,
  `infourl` text NOT NULL,
  `extra_query` varchar(1000) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`update_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Available Updates';
```

Just replace ##### with your table prefix

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. I simply used:

```
DROP TABLE xxxxx.updates
```

followed by

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `XXXXX_updates` (
  `update_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `update_site_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `extension_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `element` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `type` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `folder` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `client_id` tinyint(3) DEFAULT 0,
  `version` varchar(32) DEFAULT '',
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `detailsurl` text NOT NULL,
  `infourl` text NOT NULL,
  `extra_query` varchar(1000) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`update_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Available Updates';
```

Replace the phrase `XXXXX` with your own string

Answer (score 1):

I tried this solution but got this error message:

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1005 - Can't create table 'CPANELNAME_jml3_2015.j30_updates' (errno: -1) (Details…)

I tried many things including trying to create the table manually as well as restoring a previous MySQL backup which failed when it got to the 'j30_updates' table and just stopped there so no following tables were created which basically crashed the site.

Nothing worked.

My solutions was I restored from the previous MySQL backup, created a copy of the MySQL backup, manually deleted everything up to and including the 'j30_updates' table so I could restore the following tables.  Then I manually created a table with the 14 columns and added the columns manually.  This worked!  I was able to do Joomla updates again and the site pulled up.  Great!

At this point I have no clue what caused this but it has happened on two of my client websites so far.  The previous client I had this problem on was a 'very small' website so I just rebuilt it.  However, this clients website was extensive so I kept working with the tables until I got it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently with the following error when trying to recreate the updates table:

```
#1146 - Table 'xxxxxxxx_joomla.yyy_updates' doesn't exist
```

In phpMyAdmin, the updates table was appearing in the table list in the left hand column but strangely not appearing in the main list.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8410497/1983389, restarting MySQL allows you to create the table as per the other answers.

In my case the web hosting support staff were unresponsive over the holiday season so I backed up the website using Akeeba Backup, deleted the website files, deleted and recreated the database and restored the website using Kickstart. I was then able to recreate the updates table so the website is again functioning normally.

[image: #1146 Table doesn't exist]